# How do you ensure an object conforms to a Typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, instanceof, static-typing

how I could validate that an object has all the properties of an interface.

For example:

```
interface Vehicle {
 name: string 
 model: string
}

interface User {
 Name: string
 age: númber
}

interface Customer extends User  {
 vehicles: Vehicle[]
}
```

How could I check that an object has all the properties of `Customer` interface????

Comment: Isn't that the job of typescript? Maybe you need to ask a different question, like what is your use case? You have a bunch of interfaces, but no object. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wR9bYW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2):

### if you mean *static type checking*...

If by "validate that an object has all the properties of an interface" you mean *static type checking*, well that's Typescripts job and it will do that at compile time when you assign the object to a variable of that interface type. e.g.:

```
const obj = {name: 'Edwin', age: 35}

let c: Customer = obj // this will fail at compile time
```

### if you mean *runtime type checking...*

Typescript at runtime is just Javascript, and Javascript does not have support interface definitions. In fact, once Typescript is *transpiled* to Javascript before execution, `Vehicle`, `User` and `Customer` will no longer exist due to *type erasure*. For more info see these [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types) and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) in the Typescript Handbook and docs. This means you cannot even reference these types in any runtime logic.

The Javascript `instanceof` operator only works for Javascript prototype inheritance, and has very specific meaning:

> The instanceof operator tests to see if the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. The return value is a boolean value.
>
> ~ [instanceof | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

The Javascript `typeof` operator only works for primitive types, like `string`.

If you need to do runtime "type checking", you will have to do it manually, checking for the existence of each field, and its primitive type recursively.

Typescript has some syntactic sugar to make such manual checks look natural in your Typescript source code. Read about [Narrowing and Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

There are some libraries that do this for you. Here are some examples (there are more):

- https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts
- https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes
- https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime
- https://github.com/janjakubnanista/ts-type-checked